# reloadData() on UICollectionView change contenteOffset with dynamics cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I just updated my app for iOS 12 and I found this problem with my collectionView. I'm using self sizing cells this way on my collectionView subclass :

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 44)
    layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
}
```

When I'm calling reloadData(), the contentOffset is changing where it doesn't have to. I've tried a workaround that worked perfectly well on on iOS 11 by is overriding reloadData() :

```
override func reloadData() {
    let oldOffset = contentOffset

    super.reloadData()
    layoutSubviews() // This line do the job with iOS 11.

    self.setContentOffset(oldOffset, animated: false)
}
```

But on iOS 12 it doesn't work anymore and the contentOffset is completely broken when calling reloadData()
I've also tried to `invalidateLayout()` instead of `layoutSubviews()` but doesn't work too.

Can someone explain me why and give me a potential solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed the same thing with a table view.

Comment: According to apples documentation you should never call `layoutSubviews()` 

> If you want to force a layout update, call the `setNeedsLayout()` method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the `layoutIfNeeded()` method.

[layoutSubviews()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I've tried with `layoutIfNeeded()` instead of `layoutSubviews()` but it still doesn't works. I just don't understand this bug.